Get domain local group membership of another domain in the same forest
My Active Directory Forest consists of multiple child domains, including:

Main domain (main.contoso.local)
Test domain (test.contoso.local)

My user david@main.contoso.local is member of group MAIN\Global which is of GroupScope Global and resides in the main domain. This global group is member of group TEST\DomainLocal which is of GroupScope Domain Local and resides in the test domain.
[david@main.contoso.local]  --MemberOf-->  [MAIN\Global]  --MemberOf-->  [TEST\DomainLocal]
  

If my user logs on to a machine in the test domain, the token will include the SID of TEST\DomainLocal. This can be verified with whoami /groups in the session of the user.
As an administrator, how can I get this information via CLI without being logged on as the user? I have tried querying the global catalog or using the LDAP_MATCHING_RULE_IN_CHAIN (member:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941), however the TEST\DomainLocal does not show up anywhere.

Domain local Groups are specifically not replicated outside of their domain, this includes the Global Catalog.  This is by design, and the reason why this group scope exists.  If you would like to get the membership of a principal in each domain, including domain local groups, you would need to query each domain separately.
Or, you could change the scope from a DomainLocal group to a Universal group, which can accept members from other domains.
Or, you could design it such that a universal group from MAIN domain is only and specifically used in a domain local group in TEST, so that you can see which DLGs the user is a member of by just reviewing the memberships in MAIN.
This last option most closely resembles how AD best practices and exams were taught. Following that teaching, a user from a different domain is not supposed to be a direct member of a Domain Local Group in any domain; Universal groups are supposed to be members of Domain Local Groups -- but that's getting pretty deep in the weeds.  It is all about controlling replication scope and reducing the amount and frequency of replications. In a modern world, bandwidth and latency are significantly less of a factor, and some of these practices have fallen by the wayside.

you would need to query each domain separately - this is exactly the part I cannot seem to figure out. I guessed I have to query every domain in the forest to get all domain local groups. But what would be the query? There must be a way, because how else would a domain controller of those domains build the correct token.

I guess, how is it relevant? Resources in domain TEST do not need to know about domain local groups from domain MAIN.  You can't use these groups in this manner anyway  If you find yourself needing to do that, the design is off; you're looking at a use case for universal groups.

All I can figure would be that you're looking to perform some kind of audit, or somey, to enumerate all access for a particular account across multiple domains -- and again, I go back to group design, and leveraging dedicated universal groups nested into domain local groups.  Users in domain MAIN should not be in local groups in domain TEST; it will greatly simplify a task like this, and follows appropriate group design and function.

I fully agree with you, it's just that as a company where hundred of IT guys are working together, not everyone acts the same :) . I asked this question because when I am looking at a user, in order to improve the group memberships, I have to know what's going on first. Right now this task takes a long time because information is not in one place. I want a script which can pull that information for me.
